Solving a system of nonlinear equations - degree 4
I need help in solving the following system of nonlinear equations analytically,
$$x^4+2y^3-x=\frac{-1}{4}+3\sqrt{3}$$
$$y^4+2x^3-y=\frac{-1}{4}-3\sqrt{3}$$
I tried adding and subtracting the equations to get an equivalent system, and I got something like $f(x)-f(y)=6\sqrt{3}$ where $f(z)=z^4-2z^3-z$ and $g(x)+g(y)=-\frac{1}{2}$ where $g(z)=z^4+2z^3-z$. However, this did not help me in parametrizing the equation, or get any closer to solving it. How would you find the solution set to such a system?

Are the equations correct? According to WolframAlpha there exist no real solutions to the given system.

Is the bottom equation meant to have a $-y$ oppose to a $-x$?

Do you have any reason to believe the result is not awful?  Eliminating $x$, I get a degree 16 polynomial for $y$ having eight complex conjugate pairs of roots, and a degree 15 polynoimal in $y$ to recover $x$ from each root.

@AndrewSotomayor : Well, that version has one solution over the reals...

@AndrewSotomayor Yes, you are right. That was a typing error, which I have now fixed.

You are asked to solve the system of equations (modified to make it symmetric)
$$f(x,y)=x^4+2y^3-x+\frac{1-12 \sqrt{3}}{4} \tag 1$$
$$g(x,y)=y^4+2x^3-y+\frac{1+12 \sqrt{3}}{4} \tag 2$$
It is so complicated that there must be a trap somewhere that is to say a simple relation between the solutions. Looking at the constants, I bet (do not ask me why) that $$x=-(1+y)$$ Compute
$$h(y)=f\Big(-(1+y),y\Big)-g\Big(-(1+y),y\Big)$$
$$h(y)=8 y^3+12 y^2+12 y+4-6 \sqrt{3}$$ has the good idea to factor as
$$h(y)=\left(2 y-\sqrt{3}+1\right) \left(4
   y^2+2 \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right) y+\sqrt{3}+7\right)$$ The quadratic does not show real solution.
Then $\cdots\cdots~~?$ and we have the unique real solutions of the problem.
Edit
If you do not see the factorization of the cubic, just use the hyperbolic solution (since $\Delta=-193536$ shows that there is only one real root). The formula to use is simple and, if you simplify it, you get the result.

I came up with something similar too, but figured that proving the simple relation between $x$ and $y$ is the heart of the problem.

Graphically we can see that if  we get  $y=f(x)$  then $f^{-1}(y)=x$, both curves are symmetric each other respect the diagonal $y=x$ and don't have intersection.  Besides the point $\left(\dfrac{-\sqrt3-1}{2},\dfrac{\sqrt3-1}{2}\right)$ occurs out of the curves.

COMMENT (NOT AN ANSWER).-Graphically the two curves we can see are disjoint, so no  solution really; however if the system change  $-x$ by $-y$ in the second equation (as seems reasonable by symmetry) the intersection is not empty. Anyway, simply by fun, I show here a “method” to do something with the proposed system.
The two RHS are roots of the equation $16x^2+8x-431=0$ so we can put twice (with the first and second LHS)
$$16(LHS)^2+8(LHS)-431=0$$ which yields $2(-\dfrac12+1)(6\sqrt3)=0$. I laugh at this  but I also wonder if this correctly deduced result is not proof that the proposed system is incompatible.

You are right, there was a typing error in the original system, which I have now fixed. Even if, reading further revealed the typing error rather quickly, however I am fully to blame for that error of course.
